# dismiss location services request dialog

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

at the start of my UI test I have

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
    let button = alert.buttons["Allow"]
    if button.exists {
        snapshot("request location service")
        button.tap()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

which should dismiss the location services request dialog, but it does nothing and it never reaches the handler. I have also tried to set this code in `setUp()` but it didn't work either.

I think the problem might be that the first thing that happens in the app is that the dialog is being shown, it may be too soon (it may happen before `addUIInterruptionMonitor` is called)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to interact with the app right after adding the UIInterruptionMonitor. This can be a simple tap:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
   let button = alert.buttons["Allow"]
   if button.exists {
   button.tap()
      return true
   }
   return false
}
// interact with the app
app.tap()
```

If `app.tap()` interferes with your test you could also use `app.swipeUp()`

Be aware that the location service permission dialog changed in **iOS11**. There are now 3 Buttons, so you have to use `alert.buttons["Always Allow"]` to dismiss the dialog.

[image]